# What is throttled search query in azure search?

Tags: azure, azure-cognitive-search

I'm using azure search for my app, and lately i'm facing performance issues.
Currently i'm investigating problem and i came across the following article:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/search/search-performance-optimization#scaling-azure-search-for-high-query-rates-and-throttled-requests

It says:

> **Scaling Azure Search for high query rates and throttled requests**
>
> When you are receiving too many throttled requests or exceed your target
> latency rates from an increased query load, you can look to decrease
> latency rates in one of two ways: Increase Replicas: A replica is like
> a copy of your data allowing Azure Search to load balance requests
> against the multiple copies. All load balancing and replication of
> data across replicas is managed by Azure Search and you can alter the
> number of replicas allocated for your service at any time. You can
> allocate up to 12 replicas in a Standard search service and 3 replicas
> in a Basic search service. Replicas can be adjusted either from the
> Azure portal or PowerShell. Increase Search Tier: Azure Search comes
> in a number of tiers and each of these tiers offers different levels
> of performance. In some cases, you may have so many queries that the
> tier you are on cannot provide sufficiently low latency rates, even
> when replicas are maxed out. In this case, you may want to consider
> leveraging one of the higher search tiers such as the Azure Search S3
> tier that is well suited for scenarios with large numbers of documents
> and extremely high query workloads.

Now i can't figure out what throttled requests means.
Google didn't help!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Azure Search starts throttling requests when the error rate (requests failing with 207 or 503 status codes) exceeds a certain threshold. The best strategy is to use an exponential retry policy on 207 and 503 responses to control the load and avoid throttling altogether.

Throttled requests have the `throttle-reason` response header that contains information about why the request was throttled. It appears we haven't documented that; we'll work on fixing that.

Comment: Thanks for an answer!

Comment: do you know if it's possible to get the throttle-reason out when using the C# SDK for Azure Search? Thanks!